# Image Slider Javascript won't work

Tags: javascript, image, slider

I'm currently working on an image slider for my company's new homepage and just can't figure out the error that seems to lie in the javascript part ..
The slider contains 4 images and should, as soon as the last image is reached, begin at the first image again. The problem is that the images are displayed in that order "1-2-1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4..."

Here the code:

```
  $('.slide').first().addClass('active');

  $('.slide').hide();

  $('.active').show();

  $('#next').on('click', nextSlide);

  $('#prev').on('click', prevSlide);

  // Auto slider
  if (options.autoswitch === true) {
    setInterval(nextSlide, options.autoswitch_speed);
  }

  function nextSlide() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('prevActive');    

    if ($('.prevActive').is(':last-child')) {   
      $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
    } else {                   
      $('.prevActive').next().addClass('active');
    }   

    $('.prevActive').removeClass('prevActive');   
    $('.slide').fadeOut(options.speed);        
    $('.active').fadeIn(options.speed);       
  }

  function prevSlide() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('prevActive');    

    if ($('.prevActive').is(':first-child')) {    
      $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
    } else {                    
      $('.prevActive').prev().addClass('active');
    }

    $('.prevActive').removeClass('prevActive');   
    $('.slide').fadeOut(options.speed);       
    $('.active').fadeIn(options.speed);           
  }

});
```

and the corresponding CSS:

```
#slider-container {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
}

#sldier {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#slider .slide img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

#prev, #next {
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  z-index: 999;
}

#prev { left: 12px; }

#next { right: 3px; }

#slider-container:hover #prev, #slider-container:hover #next { opacity: .7; }

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide-copy {
  background: #777;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}   

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #prev, #next {
        top: 45%;
    }
    }
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="slider-container">
  <img src="img/arrowprev" id="prev" alt="prev">
  <ul id="slider">
    <li class="slide">
      <div class="slide-copy">
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="img/placeholder" alt="placeholder">
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <div class="slide-copy">
        <h2>Placeholder2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="img/placeholder" alt="placeholder">
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <div class="slide-copy">
        <h2>Placeholder3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="img/placeholder" alt="placeholder">
    </li>
        <li class="slide">
      <div class="slide-copy">
        <h2>Placeholder4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="img/placeholder" alt="placeholder">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <img src="img/arrownext" id="next" alt="next">     
</div>
```

Maybe it has something to do with

```
if ($('.prevActive').is(':first-child')) {    
      $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
```

I just can't figure out the problem and would appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance :)

This is the page I took as source:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Tiny-jQuery-Image-Slider-Slideshow-With-Caption-Support.html

Comment: Hi! If you don't attach the HTML, it's difficult to figure it out what's happenning

Comment: Sure sorry, I just edited it

Answer (score 0):

I found the fail, the unique thing it wasn't working, is the apply of visibility on each `prevActive` and `active` elements on each next/prev actions, so I've added this lines to both functions:

```
$('.prevActive').hide();
$('.active').show();
```

(Also I've commented the lines referencing to options variable, as is not defined in the description).

You can see the fiddle working here:
https://jsfiddle.net/a4bssrf5/8/

Comment: Hm I see that it works on your fiddle, but somehow it won't work for me.. Could it be that it has something to do with WordPress? Or did I maybe miss any changes to HTML/CSS?

Comment: I don't know.. but yes, WordPress can always make things more complicated. What error do you have printed in the browser Console?